# Page Object Model or External property file for Selenium Object Repository

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I am a beginner in Selenium WebDriver (Java with TestNg). I'm trying to create a framework of my own.

My question here is what would be the better option to store my objects (my object repository) Page Object Model or External Property file? Why? Is there a better method than those?

Comment: I suggest looking at Geb with Page Objects (and Spock); it's what I use for all of my Selenium tests.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sam. Just a heads up...this may get closed as "primarily opinion based" as it stands, so I suggest editing with a LOT more detail of what you're trying to do. What is this framework supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for the reply. can you please help me choose between Page Object Model and External Property file. @-JasonMc92, Hi thanks for the heads up. But this is exactly what I wnated to ask, which is the best solution for storing objects in a selnium test automation framework. I just hope someone would help me here as i dont know anyone who work in Selenium personally and I am very badly in need of a support. Thank you

Comment: External properties make absolutely no sense as an alternative to Page Objects.

Comment: One does not preclude the other. You can use page objects, and at the same time you can store objects' locators in the property file (or database, or whatever you want) instead of storing them "hardcoded" in the code, and then retrieve these locators from the store in the page object.

Comment: Definitely opinion based.  My personal opinion is keep them in page objects.  You will need to reference the variable in the reference file for every locator anyway so if the locator reference changes in the external file you need to change the reference in code.  It's also harder to navigate your way to the locator in an IDE if you have to go searching in an external file.

Comment: Sorry for the opinion based question. Will be cautious next time. Thanks for your replies, i am going ahead with POM.